# Why should the symmetric logarithmic derivative be linear?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, quantum-information

I recently learned about the [symmetric logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_logarithmic_derivative) $L_\rho(A)$, defined implicitly by
$$i\left[\rho,A\right]=\frac 1 2\left\{\rho,L_\rho(A)\right\}.$$
Here $\rho$ is a Hermitian, positive semi-definite matrix and $A$ is also Hermitian. This quantity is important in quantum metrology.

On the wikipedia page it is mentioned that this operator is linear:
\begin{align}
L_\rho(\mu A)&=\mu L_\rho(A)\\
L_\rho(A+B)&=L_\rho(A)+L_\rho(B)
\end{align}

This last fact confuses me. As a generalized version of the logarithmic derivative (is it?), I should expect it to behave at least somewhat like the ordinary logarithmic derivative, which has scale invariance and which does not distribute:
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{d}{dx}\ln\right](af(x))&=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\\
\left[\frac{d}{dx}\ln\right](f(x)+g(x))&=\frac{f'(x)+g'(x)}{f(x)+g(x)}\neq\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}
\end{align}
So why should we expect linearity to hold the symmetric logarithmic derivative instead of scale invariance and the product Le

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I've seen the symmetric logarithmic derivative defined is as follows.

Let $\rho(\lambda)$ be a continuously parameterized family of states. Then the logarithmic derivative of $\rho$ is defined as the operator $L_\rho$ that satisfies
$$
\frac{L_\rho\rho+\rho L_\rho}{2} = \frac{d\rho}{d\lambda}.
$$
If $\rho$ is just a one-by-one matrix, then
$$
L_\rho = \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d\rho}{d\lambda}=\frac{\rho'}{\rho},
$$
which is the regular logarithmic derivative.
That's where the name comes from.

If specifically $\rho(\lambda)=e^{-i\lambda A}\rho e^{i\lambda A}$, we get the definition you have. It no longer has the same properties that the classical logarithmic derivative has.

Comment: This is helpful! I guess the 'logarithmic behaviour' should be expected in $\rho$, not in $A$. And this behaviour also breaks down for larger matrices.